# How to prevent an infinite loop in a React Next.js custom hook that redirects based on router locale?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, i18next

I have a custom React hook useLocale in my Next.js application that aims to ensure the application always defaults to English ('en') regardless of the user's browser settings. The hook includes a useEffect that checks the router's locale and redirects to English if it's not already set to English. However, this causes an infinite loop.
The code for the useLocale hook is as follows:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useCallback, useMemo, useEffect } from "react";
import en from "@/../lang/en.json";
import fr from "@/../lang/fr.json";
import { flattenMessages } from "@/lang/flattenMessages";

const messages = {
    en,
    fr,
};

export const useLocale = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!router.locale || router.locale !== 'en') {
            // Redirect to English version
            router.push(router.asPath, router.asPath, { locale: 'en' });
        }
    }, [router.locale]);

    const flattenedMessages = useMemo(
        () => flattenMessages(messages[router.locale]),
        [router]
    );

    const switchLocale = useCallback(
        (locale) => {
            if (locale === router.locale) {
                return;
            }

            const path = router.asPath;
            return router.push(path, path, { locale });
        },
        [router]
    );
    return { locale: router.locale, switchLocale, messages: flattenedMessages };
};
```

Could anyone help me understand why the useEffect causes an infinite loop and suggest a solution to prevent this behavior while still enforcing English as the default language, or kindely if you have any other approach I would appreciate it ?

I proposed altering the dependencies array within the useEffect hook to trigger the redirection only when the router.locale changes. This change aimed to prevent the useEffect from being re-triggered constantly due to its own actions (specifically, the redirect using router.push).

I also already configured the default language to be English in the next.config.js file but it did not work , it always giving the french version as default when switching the browser language to french :

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  // instead of wrapping our Component inside <StricMode/> we set this to true.
  reactStrictMode: true,
  i18n:{
    locales: ['en', 'fr'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```